# Vue.js: How to change set of properties based on another property

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a set of divisions named as divReports0, divReports1, divReports2, etc. These are also properties in my vue model. I want to show/hide these divisions based on a value selected from a SELECT box, available in the **selectedReport** property. Here is the code I am having trouble with.

```
    showHideDivision: function()
    {
        for (var j=0; j < this.reportsList.length; j++) 
        {
            var divName = 'divReports' + this.reportsList[j]['value'];
            if (this.reportsList[j]['value'] == this.selectedReport)
            {
                console.log('Show:' + divName );
                //this.divReports+eval(this.reportsList[j]['value']) = true
            }   
            else
            {
                console.log('Hide:' + divName );
            }
        }

    },
```

I have the divsion name property to control in the divName variable. How can I assign a value to the divName property? (e.g. this.eval(divName) = false)

Comment: Are you trying to determine whether `selectedReport` appears as a `value` in `reportsList`?

Comment: You probably want each div to be `<div v-if="selectedReport === 'divReports0'>`

Comment: I have 3 divisions named as divReports0, divReports1 & divReports2. In future, I may have more divReports. The selectedReport property will have a value, such as '1' based on the selected report. The goal is to show only one division, e.g. divReports1 and hide all other (divReports0 and divReports2). I am controlling display of these divisions with v-show (e.g. v-show='divReports0', v-show='divReports1', etc.)

Comment: The issue I am facing is how to change the value of `this.divReportsX` in code where X is a variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the goal is to display only one div at a time, you should have a variable that indicates which one is to display, rather than having a boolean for each to indicate whether it is displayed.

In any case, numbering variable names (`this.divReportsX` where *X* is a variable) is almost always an indicator that you should be using an array rather than individual scalars.

In the example below, I use the [range form of `v-for`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#v-for-with-a-Range) to count my divs from 1 to 3 (or however many you want). There is `selectedReport` to indicate which div is shown. And just for fun, I included a computed `showHide` that gives you a boolean indexed by the div number so you can use `v-show=showHide[div]`

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    howManyDivs: 3,
    selectedReport: 1
  },
  computed: {
    showHide() {
      const result = [];

      for (let i=1; i <= this.howManyDivs; ++i) {
        result[i] = i === this.selectedReport;
      }
      return result;
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="//unpkg.com/vue@latest/dist/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <select v-model="selectedReport">
    <option v-for="div in howManyDivs" :value="div">Show {{div}}</option>
  </select>
  <div v-for="div in howManyDivs" v-show="showHide[div]">
    Report div
    <h1>** {{div}} **</h1>
  </div>
  <div v-for="div in howManyDivs">
    {{div}}: {{showHide[div]}}
  </div>
</div>
```